# Need to Change Date format in java

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have a two Strings. One String contain date like this `yyyymmdd` and other string contain time   like this `hhmmssff`. And i need to join the both string into one string in the format of `Tue Jul 03 14:54:24 IDT 2012`

Example

> Input:
>
> String One = 20130430; String Two = 03153020;
>
> Output:
>
> Tue Apr 30 03:15:30:20 IDT 2013;

How can I get this output in java?

Comment: Use [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you a Potted answer for this, but you could follow the below procedure to achieve what you want.

You could concatenate both the `Strings`, use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse that concatenated `String`, which would give a `Date` object. 
Printing the `Date` object will give the output in the format you need, but if you need a `String` representation of that, you need to use another `SDF`, to format that `Date` object as per your requirements.

**P.S:** The link of SDF provided also has the list of **pattern letters** to be used. Pick the ones you require in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Give your example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String One = "20130430"; String Two = "03153020";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmssSS");
    System.out.println( sdf.parse(One+Two));
}
```